# Froala editor insert image - by url only

Tags: javascript, froala

I'm using froala editor and want to limit the insert image option to **By url** only, meaning the user can insert images from their local machine, but first they have to handle the hosting.

Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
imageInsertButtons: ['imageBack', '|', 'imageByURL']
```

This worked on the options.